# Unity - Change mouse controls with rotated camera

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, rotation, rigid-bodies

I'm currently working on zero-g fps controls and have pretty much everything working how I want it, but I have a problem where when I rotate the character and the camera the controls don't change just fit. E.g. the charter is horizontal but the controls are still as if they are vertical.

Is there anyway to fix this? Here is the code I'm using. I'm fairly new to coding so be gentle with me please.

```
 public Rigidbody rb;
 public Transform camerObj;
 public Transform orientation;
 public float camRotationSpeed = 5f;
 public float cameraMinimumY = -60f;
 public float cameraMaximumY = 75f;
 public float rotationSmoothSpeed = 10f;
 public float maxSpeed = 9f;
 public float thrust = 20f;
 public float forwardSwimSpeed = 45f;
 private float xRotation;
 private float sensitivity = 50f;
 private float sensMultiplier = 1f;
 void Update()
 {
     spaceRotation();
     Look();
 }
 void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (rb.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
     {
         rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
     {
         rb.AddForce(camerObj.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * thrust) * Time.deltaTime * forwardSwimSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
     {
         rb.AddForce(camerObj.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * thrust) * Time.deltaTime * forwardSwimSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
     {
         //rb.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * thrust);
         rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0) * thrust) * Time.deltaTime * forwardSwimSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
     {
         //rb.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * thrust);
         rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(1, 0, 0) * thrust) * Time.deltaTime * forwardSwimSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
     {
         //rb.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * thrust);
         rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * thrust) * Time.deltaTime * forwardSwimSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
     {
         //rb.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * thrust);
         rb.AddForce(orientation.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(0, -1, 0) * thrust) * Time.deltaTime * forwardSwimSpeed, ForceMode.Acceleration);
     }
 }
 void spaceRotation()
 {
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
     {
         rb.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * thrust * Time.deltaTime);
     }
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
     {
         rb.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * thrust * Time.deltaTime);
     }
 }
 private float desiredX;
 private void Look()
 {
     float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * sensMultiplier;
     float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * sensMultiplier;
     Vector3 rot = camerObj.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
     desiredX = rot.y + mouseX;
     xRotation -= mouseY;
     xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
     camerObj.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, desiredX, 0);
     orientation.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, desiredX, 0);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting rid of orientation object and using the camera instead seems to do the trick.

Here's how things look for me in the hierarchy:

[image]

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody targetRigidbody;
    public Camera targetCamera;
    public float camRotationSpeed = 5f;
    public float cameraMinimumY = -60f;
    public float cameraMaximumY = 75f;
    public float rotationSmoothSpeed = 10f;
    public float maxSpeed = 9f;
    public float thrust = 20f;
    public float forwardSwimSpeed = 45f;

    private float xRotation;
    private const float Sensitivity = 50f;
    private const float SensitivityMultiplier = 1f;
    
    private float desiredX;

    private void Update()
    {
        SpaceRotation();
        Look();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (targetRigidbody.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
        {
            targetRigidbody.velocity = targetRigidbody.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            AddForce(Vector3.forward);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            AddForce(Vector3.back);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            AddForce(Vector3.left);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            AddForce(Vector3.right);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            AddForce(Vector3.up);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
            AddForce(Vector3.down);
    }

    private void AddForce(Vector3 direction)
    {
        float scaledForwardSwimSpeed = Time.deltaTime * forwardSwimSpeed;

        targetRigidbody.AddForce(targetCamera.transform.TransformDirection(
            direction * thrust) * scaledForwardSwimSpeed,
            ForceMode.Acceleration);
    }

    private void SpaceRotation()
    {
        // To avoid multiplying a vector twice
        float scaledThrust = thrust * Time.deltaTime;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
            targetRigidbody.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * scaledThrust);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            targetRigidbody.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * scaledThrust);
    }

    private void Look()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * SensitivityMultiplier;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * SensitivityMultiplier;

        Vector3 rotation = targetCamera.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
        desiredX = rotation.y + mouseX;
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        targetCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, desiredX, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly! You went above and beyond fixing all my other problems in the script, have your name under special thanks in the credits of my final game? Again, thank you!